# How to know the app is downloaded from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing one app and want to put it on Google Play no where else...

I just wanted to know, how can I know that this app is downloaded from Google Play...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout given link, may be help you.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html